# Let div disappear when container is too small

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am am working an some unique selling points(usp's) for a webshop. After 5 PM one of these usp's disappears.

[image: Normal USP Before 5 PM]

The first usp disappears after 5 PM and there will be three left.

When you view this on a tablet there should be only 3 usp's. But depending on the time or width, one should disappear when it gets viewed on smaller devices.

[image: One of the usp's should disappear]

I hope my explanation was clear. I am adjusting a script we already have to suit my needs. The javascript I have works for the the usp disappearing after 5 the javascript is:

```
<div class="main-container col1-layout">

        <div id="countdown" class="hide-below-768">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="usp">
                    <div class="feature indent countdown">
                        <span class="icon i-countdown no-bg-color"></span>
                        <p class="no-margin ">Bestel binnen 
            <strong>
                <span id="t_hours">5 uren en </span><span id="t_minutes">6 minuten</span> <span id="t_seconds"></span>
            </strong>  
            en ontvang je bestelling morgen al in huis
        </p>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var lang_hours      = 'uren';
            var lang_hour       = 'uur';
            var lang_minutes    = 'minuten';
            var lang_minute     = 'minuut';
            var lang_seconds    = 'seconden';
            var lang_second     = 'seconde';

            var Counter = Class.create();  
            Counter.prototype = {

                time_left: 0,
                keep_counting: 1,
                interval: null,

                /* 
                * INITIALIZATION - CONFIGURATION 
                */  
                initialize: function(t) {  
                    this.time_left = t;
                    this.interval = setInterval("countdown.timer()", 1000);
                    // this.timer();
                },

                timer: function() {
                    this.countdown();
                    this.format_output();
                },

                countdown: function() {
                    if(this.time_left <= 60) {
                        clearInterval(this.interval);
                        this.keep_counting = false;
                    }

                    this.time_left = this.time_left - 1;
                },

                format_output: function() {
                    if(this.keep_counting) {
                        var hours, minutes, seconds;
                        seconds = this.time_left % 60;
                        minutes = Math.floor(this.time_left / 60) % 60;
                        hours = Math.floor(this.time_left / 3600);

                        if($('t_hours')) $('t_hours').innerHTML = hours+' '+(hours == 1 ? lang_hour : lang_hours) + ' en ';
                        if($('t_hours') && hours < 1) $('t_hours').innerHTML = "";
                        if($('t_minutes')) $('t_minutes').innerHTML = minutes+' '+(minutes == 1 ? lang_minute : lang_minutes);
                        if($('t_minutes') && minutes < 1) $('t_minutes').innerHTML = "";
                        if($('t_seconds') && ( hours < 1 && minutes < 10)) $('t_seconds').innerHTML = (minutes >= 1 ? ' en ' : '') + seconds + ' ' + (seconds == 1 ? lang_second : lang_seconds);
                    } else {
                        $('countdown').remove();
                    }
                }

            };

            var countdown = new Counter(18464);
        </script>

                    </div>
                    <div class="feature indent transport">
                        <span class="icon i-transport no-bg-color"></span>
                        <p class="no-margin ">Gratis verzending binnen heel Nederland</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature indent calender">
                        <span class="icon i-calender no-bg-color"></span>
                        <p class="no-margin ">30 dagen retourrecht. Niet goed? Geld terug!</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="feature indent pay">
                        <span class="icon i-pay no-bg-color"></span>
                        <p class="no-margin ">Achteraf betalen, koop vandaag betaal over 14 dagen</p>
                    </div>



    </div>
</div>
```

How can I keep always show 3 usp's with javascript?

Comment: Can you please put the css so i can check what is issue with your CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try using responsive CSS:

for e.g:

```
@media (max-width: 420px) {
    .the-div {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check window width and with condition can enable disable the div(s).

```
var width = $( window ).width();

if(width < "your tablet width you want to set")
{
   $("your div element").fadeOut();
}
else
{
   $("your div element").fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try **overflow: hidden**. Your usp's  will not wrap when window width is small.

Answer (score 0):

My idea: You can calculate total width of "feature" classes. Then check if it plus div#countdown be oversize.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var twidth = 0;
    $(".main-container .feature").each(function(){
        twidth += $(this).width();
    });
    if(twidth + $("#countdown").width() > $(".main-container").width())
        $("#countdown").hide();
})
```

You can use **outerwidth()** instead of **width()** for better result